# unreported exception StackEmptyException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, exception

I'm not able to figure out why the push() and pop() methods of this code are no longer working (are the exceptions declared properly?).  Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the code:

```
/*
* From Schildt's Java: A Beginner's Guide, 6th ed.
* Page 628-629, 637-638
*/

// An exception for stack-full errors
class StackFullException extends Exception {
  int size;

  StackFullException(int s){
    size = s;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "\nStack is full.  Maximum size is " + size;
  }
}// end StackFullException

// An exception for stack-empty errors
class StackEmptyException extends Exception {
  public String toString(){
    return "\nStack is empty.";
  }
}// end StackEmptyException

// A stack class for characters
class Stack {
  private char stack[]; // this array holds the stack
  private int tos; // top of stack

  // Construct an empty Stack given its size
  Stack(int size){
    stack = new char[size]; // allocate memory for stack
    tos = 0;
  }

  // Construct a Stack from a Stack
  Stack (Stack ob){
    tos = ob.tos;
    stack = new char [ob.stack.length];

    // copy elements
    for (int i=0; i < tos; i++){
      stack[i] = ob.stack[i];
    }
  }

  // Construct a stack with initial values
  Stack(char a[]){
    stack = new char[a.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      try {
        push(a[i]);
      }
      catch(StackFullException exc){
        System.out.println(exc);
      }
    }
  }

  // Push characters onto the stack
  void push(char ch) throws StackFullException{
    if (tos == stack.length){
      throw new StackFullException(stack.length);
    }

    stack[tos] = ch;
    tos++;
  }

  // Pop a character from the stack
  char pop() throws StackEmptyException{
    if (tos == 0){
      throw new StackEmptyException();
    }

    tos--;
    return stack[tos];
  }
} // end Stack

// Demonstrate the Stack Class
public class StackDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]){

      // construct a 10-element empty stack
      Stack stack1 = new Stack(10);

      char name[] = {'B', 'r', 'a', 'd'};

      // construct stack from array
      Stack stack2 = new Stack(name);

      char ch = 0;
      int i;

      // put some characters into stack1
      for (i=0; i < 10; i++){
        stack1.push((char)('1' + i));
      }

      // construct stack from another stack
      Stack stack3 = new Stack(stack1);

      System.out.println();

      // show the stacks
      System.out.printf("Contents of stack1: ");
      for (i=0; i < 10; i++){
        ch = stack1.pop();
        System.out.print(ch);
      }

      System.out.println("\n");

      System.out.printf("Contents of stack2: ");
      for (i=0; i< 4; i++){
        ch = stack2.pop();
        System.out.print(ch);
      }

      System.out.println("\n");

      System.out.printf("Contents of stack3: ");
      for(i=0; i < 10; i++){
        ch = stack3.pop();
        System.out.print(ch);
      }

      System.out.println("\n");
  } // end main
} // end StackDemo
```

I know I'm a bit of a noob, and I really did try to figure this out on my own, so please be patient with your answers.

Comment: You don't handle the exceptions in your `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

If a method throws an exception ,the caller of the method should catch the exception or throw it further.

In your case the push and pop function throws  StackFullException and StackEmptyException respectively.So the caller (main method) should catch those exceptions or throw it further.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws StackFullException ,StackEmptyException 
{
}
```

or surround the push and pop functions in a try catch block

```
try
{
ch = stack1.pop();
}
catch(StackEmptyException  e)
{
}
```